# How can I place an image next to a text in CSS using Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like to create a box allowing me to have the profile photo of a user followed by his nickname on the right.

So for that, I proceeded in several ways knowing that I am using *Bootstrap 4*:

- I first tried to use the columns, but it didn't work.
- I then looked for a solution on the internet, I found some answers from some users, but it didn't seem to be the solution for me. ([This one in particular.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686097/how-to-place-image-next-to-text-css))

So I tweaked it a bit further, trying things like *flexbox* utilities, but I certainly must be doing it wrong.

I thought afterwards that it wasn't that bad, and that I was just going to ask some of you for help, being pretty sure I would find the solution here.

Let me explain myself by showing you this example:
[image: ignore the navbar]

Here is my code (I'm not organized, sorry):

```css
:root {
  --nsfr-pfp-border-radius: none;
}

.wrapper-fluid {
  padding: 8em;
}

.nsfr-pfp {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-height: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: var(--nsfr-pfp-border-radius);
}

.nsfr-pfp-wrap {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  float:left;
}

.wrap {
  clear: both;
  background-color: var(--wrap);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 2em 3.4em;
}

.username {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: var(--body-color);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="wrapper-fluid">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="nsfr-pfp-wrap">
                        <img class="nsfr-pfp" alt="Profile Picture"
                            src="https://www.nosfera.app/build/i/_global/user_default.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1 class="username">
                        Jesztar
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

If a few things are missing, please let me know.

By the way, I'm still new to front-end development, so please be indulgent and forgive my lack of knowledge.

Comment: @Pete : Not really, as shown in [the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcSgQ.png) I provided, I would really like a rounded box with some padding in between the borders of the box and the content in it.

Comment: @Pete : Yes, I do know that. This is why I made this question appear on Stack Overflow, otherwise I would've simply checked in Bootstrap's documentation.

Answer (score 3):

There are just so many ways to do it:

- Code it yourself
- Use `.card` Bootstrap component like what @Pete said
- Use flexbox utilities from Bootstrap

I will show you Bootstrap card component way:

```html
<div class="card rounded">
    <div class="card-body"> 
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle" alt="Profile Picture"
                        src="https://www.nosfera.app/build/i/_global/user_default.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 ml-md-auto">
                <h5 class="card-title">
                    Username
                </h5>
                <p>
                    Biography, and other details
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

- `.rounded`: [Bootstrap component class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/borders/#border-radius) to set the border-radius to the default value
- I use `.card-body` to give it some paddings. You can also use [Spacing utility](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/spacing/) from Bootstrap too. For example, `.p-3`.
- `.img-fluid` from [Bootstrap responsive image component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/content/images/#responsive-images) to make the profile image responsive.
- `.rounded-circle` Bootstrap component again sets the profile image's border-radius to even more rounded
- `.ml-md-auto` is to set the margin left auto up to md breakpoint. I just like to have a little gap between left and right section.

You see there are many component and utilities classes from Bootstrap you can use if you don't want to code it yourself. I would just highly recommend you read through Bootstrap documentation one time to get yourself familiarize it.

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/pj6tq135/10/

Comment: It looks almost like what I would like, only downside I would like to know how can I widen the space between the elements and the outline of the box.

Comment: @AndrzejJesztar: You can add spacing utility I mentioned on `.card-body`, something like `p-4`, `p-5`, etc? If you want more paddings, just style it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out to fix it by managing the "row" class that I forgotten in writing my code.